# Calculate sum in Excel with C# from an exported table from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have the following problem. I want to have calculated in an Excel file the sum of a column. The column is exported from SAP with a code.

Unfortunately it does not work to create a sum. To do this, I would have to click on individual cell and click on the triangle with exclamation mark next to it that says

> The number in this cell is formatted as text or there is an apostrophe

After I press "Convert to a number" it works. I would like to solve this somehow with C# and can't find an approach that helps me in any way. Can someone help me with this?

I have already written C# code to calculate the sum, but since it works manually in Excel only once you change the cells, there must be something with the cells that needs to be changed.

This is my approach so far:

```
private void CalculateAndWriteSum(IXLWorksheet worksheet, int startRow)
{
    int previousRowIndex = 0;

    foreach (var dataRow in worksheet.Rows(startRow, worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber()))
    {
        int currentRowIndex = dataRow.RowNumber();

        if (currentRowIndex - previousRowIndex > 1)
        {
            double sum = 0;

            for (int rowIndex = previousRowIndex + 1; rowIndex < currentRowIndex; rowIndex++)
            {
                var cellValue = worksheet.Cell(rowIndex, 11).GetValue<double>(); // Convert cell value to double
                sum += cellValue;
            }

            worksheet.Cell(previousRowIndex + 1, 11).Value = sum;
        }

        previousRowIndex = currentRowIndex;
    }

    // Calculate and insert sum in the last row
    int lastRowIndex = worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();

    if (lastRowIndex - previousRowIndex > 0)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int rowIndex = previousRowIndex + 1; rowIndex <= lastRowIndex; rowIndex++)
        {
            var cellValue = worksheet.Cell(rowIndex, 11).GetValue<double>(); // Convert cell value to double
            sum += cellValue;
        }

        worksheet.Cell(lastRowIndex + 1, 11).Value = sum;
    }
}
```

I would be very happy if someone can help me.

Comment: So what exactly are you having issues with? Does this actually loop through the worksheet properly and the sum just isn't working? Does it error out with datatype issues? Is the sum working, but the result is not what you're expecting?

Whenever you ask a question on SO (and welcome to SO btw), be as detailed as you can be with exactly what you're having issues with. AKA what works and what doesn't. If you have a small sample of input data, expected output data, and what your current output is doing, we can help significantly better.

Comment: If you have access to the SQL Server database why are you trying to sum in Excel? In any case, *Don't* export numbers as text to begin with. That's a bug, plain and simple. If you want sums, the easy solution would be to modify the code that generates the Excel file to include totals in the tables.

Comment: Since you're using ClosedXML, you can display totals automatically as shown in [Using Tables](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Using-Tables). If you use one of the methods shown in the `Inserting Data/Tables` to insert a collection or DataTable to the sheet, you have access to the new table and can style it

Comment: Finally, you can use ClosedXML itself to [evaluate a formula](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Evaluating-Formulas). The doc example actually uses `SUM()` - `ws.Cell("C1").FormulaA1 = "\"The total value is: \" & SUM(A1:B2)";`. After that, calling `var r = ws.Cell("C1").Value;` will try to evaluate the formula and produce a result

Comment: There are many ways to *make* it work. But why are you introducing C#? Is it a requirement? Excel...well...excels at number crunching. If a number is imported as a string the error is in the import. Fix that or use Excel's VALUE() function in an adjacent column to convert the string.